# Unable to deserialize multiple objects using XML Serializer, getting InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xmlserializer, xml-deserialization

I have a simple class Cust, which I want to serialize using XML Serialization.

```
public class Cust

{
public string CustName;
public int ID;
public Cust() { }
public Cust(string nm, int id)
{
CustName = nm;
ID = id;
}
public string DisInfo()
{
return CustName+" "+ID;
}

}
```

My Serialization Function is :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
//Serialize
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\tmp\cust.xml", FileMode.Create);
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Cust));
Cust c1 = new Cust("Rahul S",111);
Cust c2 = new Cust("John D", 222);

xs.Serialize(fs, c1);
xs.Serialize(fs, c2);
fs.Close();
}
```

The output is cust.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Cust xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CustName>Rahul S</CustName>
  <ID>111</ID>
</Cust><?xml version="1.0"?>
<Cust xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CustName>John D</CustName>
  <ID>222</ID>
</Cust>
```

Then I tried to de-serialize ; get back the Cust objects from xml file

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

//Deserialize

FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\tmp\cust.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Cust));

Cust c1 = (Cust)xs.Deserialize(fs);//Exception
Cust c2 = (Cust)xs.Deserialize(fs);

fs.Close();

}
```

This throws exception that

InvalidOperationException Unhandled- Error in XML Document (5,10)

I know I can store multiple object if I put them in a collection.

But In that case i wont be able to append the list in xml file. I want to serialize multiple objects individually and one by one; then I want to deserialize them.

Comment: Xml can have a single root node. Wrap your objects in a single object (or use an array of them)

Comment: Yes, I understand that all objects can be put into a array & stored in xml. But then how will I append that?
Means If I want to add more objects later how will I do that?

Comment: No such thing. You will read the xml and write the new one back. Xml is not a Database.

Comment: But In normal Serialization, like Binary Serialization, We can add more objects in existing file & read them all. Is it not possible with XML Serialization???

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of  objects

```
//Serialize
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\tmp\cust.xml", FileMode.Create);
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Cust[]));
Cust c1 = new Cust("Rahul S",111);
Cust c2 = new Cust("John D", 222);

xs.Serialize(fs, new[]{c1,c2});
fs.Close();
```

---

```
//Deserialize

FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\tmp\cust.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Cust[]));

Cust[] c1 = (Cust[])xs.Deserialize(fs);//Exception

fs.Close();
```

Comment: How will I append the info in XML later, if I want to add more Customer objects

Comment: You can play with XML attributes to get the desired effect. XmlElement, XmlArray, XmlAttribute, XmlRoot etc...

Comment: Can you show how? I want to save objects in XML not collection. & retrieve them later using deserialization.

Comment: Try for example `XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Cust[]),new XmlRootAttribute("Customers"));`

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to (somehow) separate each XML from the other.

1. use `XmlWriter` to serialize an object to the file (compact format, no tabs/new lines)
2. Append a new line to the file (after the serialized message)
3. Repeat for all your objects
4. Use `StreamReader.ReadLine` to read the file line by line, each line representing a complete XML document
5. Create a memory stream for each line you just read and deserialize your object from it